# What does the e3 or e4 printed on an IC mean?

Tags: components, markings

So after staring at a few ICs today, I was wondering what the "e3" or "e4" stands for on the top of an IC. For example, here is an e3:

[image]

Comment: interesting -- i've never noticed this!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is regarding the lead content or plating finish.  Here is an excerpt from **IPC/JEDEC J-STD-609**:

> e0 - contains intentionally added lead (Pb)
>
> e1 - SnAgCu (shall not be included in category e2)
>
> e2 - Sn alloys with no Bi or Zn excluding SnAgCu
>
> e3 - Sn
>
> e4 - Preplated (e.g., Ag, Au, NiPd, NiPdAu)
>
> e5 - SnZn, SnZnx (no Bi)
>
> e6 - contains Bi
>
> e7 - low temperature solder (\$\le\$ 150C) containing Indium (no Bi)
>
> e8, e9 - unassigned

Comment: Oh wow, excellent. Thank you for that great answer. John.